# How to compile/build and run Objective-C program in Ubuntu using Terminal?

Tags: software-installation, objective-c

So here I have the basic "hello world" script for Objective-C, I have Ubuntu on my laptop and want to use Ubuntu to start compiling basic ideas, extra classes, or anything worth coding for any of my current projects on the go, so that way I can code a little bit wherever I am and not always have to be on my iMac.

[image: helloworld.m]

Now my only question is how do I build and run this code in terminal? Obviously it's not that important since I'm coding for iOS and OSX so the only code that will display is anything that doesn't call on the SDK's or Cocoa scripts, so basically it should only display basic text commands such as "NSLog" or whatever, you get the just of what I'm trying to do, which is what I want. That way I can check for small errors at the very least.

I've looked around and I've found several helps for default shell scripts and such that call on the gcc directory or something of the sort from my understanding. I have created my own folder for Objective-C projects located in my documents and I had no idea if that is effecting my ability to run the file using the terminal commands that I've tried or not, but in case it is I store the projects in:

Home>Documents>Objective-C>helloworld.m

Also when running the command line:

```
gcc -o helloworld.m
```

or this

```
gcc -I/home/caseyerdmann/Documents/Objective-C/helloworld.m
```

or any version of that command line I receive this error:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I believe I have all the compiler files installed but I am not opposed to a full tutorial, whatever gets this running. Now to clarify and gather a visual aid for you guys to try and help me better my text file is located in my documents:

[image: filedirectory]

And you can visually see the directory it is placed in.
Now when I run any of the commands above that I have tried in terminal it yields this result:

[image: terminal]

It doesn't matter which command I use it is always that. I hope this helps a little bit more to provide an answer for my situation.
I am not opposed to a full tutorial and having to save my file elsewhere or make any other changes by any means, in fact it'd be appreciated! I just would love to get this running.

I did some research and noticed the answers on this already are providing me with help to run the hello.m script that comes inside the GNUstep libraries, this is not what I am trying to do. However because I'm having trouble getting the default script to run I think I may have another problem as well, I'm going to continue researching to see if I can get that script to run, in the mean time any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I have tried a new command and yielded a new result, though it was also unsuccessful in compiling I think it may help answer others to answer this. This is what I tried:

```
gcc -o helloworld.m -lobjc
```

and this was the result:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you installed a Objective C compiler and compiled the code?

Comment: I have GNU Step installed but I'm not sure how to use it to compile the code, I only have it written in gedit and saved in objective-c format as helloworld.m in the directory listed.

Comment: The `-o` option is to specify the name of the executable to be produced (the default is `a.out`). You should write `gcc helloworld.m -o HelloWorld  -lobjc` where `HelloWorld` is the name of the executable.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now, however it still did not work. Maybe it's an error with GNUstep? I read something about having to make a shell script because gcc can't recognize where the file is? If so how to I do this? Or is that incorrect?

Comment: Please provide the output the command I put in the previous comment, also make sure you are on the right directory and your file is called `helloworld.m`

Comment: The output I received was the same as the others:

gcc: error: helloworld.m: No such file or directory

and I am almost positive it's the right directory, I'm just not sure gcc recognizes it.

Comment: Type `ls` and see if the file is in the output.

Comment: Yes it seems to have located my file here is my output:
a.out    Documents  examples.desktop  hello.d  Music     Public     Ubuntu One
Desktop  Downloads  GNUstep           hello.m  Pictures  Templates  Videos

 and now I have this error:
Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little research and found a solution that works for now. I'll probably post a new question to see if there is a way to shorten this. But this successfully compiles my code. Thank you to everyone who provided some help, I definitely learned some new things.

```
gcc -o hello hello.m \
    -I `gnustep-config --variable=GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_HEADERS` \
    -L `gnustep-config --variable=GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES` \
    -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString \
    -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS
```

Comment: Thanks for the command. You still need `-lobjc`

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, go ahead and install GNU objective-c compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc
```

Verify the version:

```
gcc --version
```

must say something like:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
....
```

Install GNUStep development libraries (equivalent to Cocoa on macosx):

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-devel
```

It should work and compile with:

```
gcc HelloWorld.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --base-libs` -o HelloWorld
```

You should run with:

```
./HelloWorld
```

Comment: Thanks. This procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the name for executable file. So, the command should be like:

```
gcc -o hello helloworld.m
```

After compilation, type

```
./hello
```

`-o hello` specifies the name of the output file you wish to create once the source is compiled. (In this case the output file name is `hello`.) This will create an executable file (named `hello`) which you, then, can run directly from the terminal. If you don't use `-o` option while compiling, the name of the executable file will be `a.out` by default. Now to execute that program, you need to type

```
./hello
```

The above commands assume you are already in the location of the source files, but both the source file and target output file may also be specified as a directory. For example:

```
gcc -o ~/Projects/hello ~/Desktop/hello.c
```

will compile a C source file located on your desktop and place the executable binary in a `Projects`
folder in your home directory. To run this executable, type;

```
./Projects/hello
```

Or you can also first go to the directory where the source file is located and run above commands. You do not need specify pathnames if you're in the same directory where your source file is.

I'm wondering why your file extension is `.m` instead of `.c`.

Comment: That makes sense, however it did not work.
I don't quite understand what that is calling for though, I understand GCC is my compiler/program I'm using to run my code in termianl, but what directory is "-o" calling on and why is "hello" needed before helloworld.m when it is not anywhere in my file or related to it. And while the executable file name being needed makes sense, I don't actually have one It's just a text file typed in gedit saved in objective-c format. I'll try and update my question to be more descriptive of my problem to see if that yields a better result.

Comment: man gcc will output the manual pages for gcc.  I suggest you do some reading. "-o foobar" simply says output a file named foobar, instead of the default, which is a.out.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -o hello hello.m
```

should produce the objective c executable if the compiler is installed.
If not, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc
```

Comment: The result of running the first command, which i tweaked to use the correct file name of my project, ended in this result:
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

I also checked to see if gobjc was installed by running the second command, and it is in fact installed. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Sounds like you used the wrong file name.  Did you get the case correct and don't have any nasty things like spaces in the name?

Comment: well I used your exact command at first but then I realized that my file name isn't hello.m so I entered this exactly:

"gcc -o helloworld.m"

However, my file is located in my documents, I feel like there’s a line I'm missing to help locate the file in my documents I just don't know what the command is.